# SIM900 + GPS Module making http rest calls

Tags: tinygps

I am wondering if its possible to program a board that is developed using SIM900 and GPS module to make http rest calls.

I found [this library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23842394/c-c-http-client-library-for-embedded-projects). My question is, will I need a microcontroller for this ?

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, will I need a microcontroller for this ?

**Yes.** There are certain things that you need a "man in the middle" to control. Without a microcontroller, how will you tell it what site to visit? How often to send the HTTP request? How to format the HTTP request? Is there any other thing you need this to do?

People often hope that they can hook up two **complex** devices that are almost setup to be slaves (like shields, sensors, and outputs) to a microprocessor. Unless the two were specifically designed to work together (or they use a standard, very specific protocol), your chances of building this without a microchip is like trying to build a skyscraper with popsicle sticks. It's possible, but there are cheaper and much easier/more efficient ways to doing that.

*Well, they're both SPI/I2C/UART/USB/Serial! Why not?* Well, although we're all humans and we use verbal communication as a protocol, do we all understand each other? Not really... For those protocols, they're designed to have a "master" and a "slave." A master would be powerful and have control over all the slaves. Hooking a GSM and GPS shield together is like hooking two slave devices together. It's not going to work out (unless you're aiming for blue smoke...)

**tl;dr:** you trying to mix two things that don't mix. Buy an Arduino Nano clone for $8 and have your circuit actually work.

Comment: Going by the cost of Arduino, I am getting inclined to go for SIM900 boards.

Comment: @Siddharth does the SIM900 have a MCU that you can program?

Answer (score 1):

I partially agree to [Anonymous Penguin's](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/3468/19127) answer.

But if you want go for a deep dive, actually SIM900 / SIM800 GSM modules also have a facility called Embedded AT. Just Google it using "SIM900 Embedded AT". They have a pdf [here](http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/sim900_embedded_at_application_note_v1.01.pdf) at the time of writing this.

According to this application note, SIM900 is actually ARM core and using Embedded AT you can utilize most of things you do in External MCU. So if you are thinking of some application, which can be developed into SIM900, Yes you can avoid using external MCU. You can give AT Commands from your application to SIM900 core using API. You even get 1 UART to interface GPS chip with SIM900. If you move to SIM800 family they have more UARTs.

PS: I haven't used it.